# How To Download iOS App Configuration File From GitHub Private Repository

Tags: iphone, ios, github

I am working on an iPhone game and would like to set it up to download configuration data so I can put up a build and then I or my teammates can make changes and just rerun the game rather than rebuild (and for non-programmers, redistribute the build).

This is basically an easy thing to do, I can set it up to download from a public Dropbox or FTP using NSURL no problem.

However, we are using GitHub for revision control, so it would be nice to download the file from GitHub and then we get the advantages of having configuration data under revision control without having to manually copy the file to a share when it's modified (need to commit/push obviously but that's already part of the workflow). Note that I don't need to check the file out or do any actual revision control operations on it as it won't be modified by the app, I just need the app to acquire the latest revision of the file.

GitHub allows web-based browsing of repositories, so it seems like this problem should reduce to downloading a file from a URL, but since our repository is private I'm not sure how to handle the authentication. It looks like the NSURLConnection class can handle authentication, but I've tried to set that up and I can't get my file. I'm honestly not even sure if this is possible with GitHub's authentication system. I unfortunately do not have much of an HTTP or Web development background, so for me this is a situation where I don't know what I don't know about approaching the problem.

I searched around a bit on Google and SO and was surprised I didn't find any straightforward examples of doing this sort of thing, I figured downloading application data from source control would be a pretty common thing to do; the GitHub private repository part obviously makes it a bit special but it seems like everyone is using GitHub these days.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you consider your configuration data to be super-secret, it might be easier to just set up a post-receive hook in your central repo that exports the data to a URL that doesn't require authentication.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, I think I'll give it a shot. I didn't even know about post-receive hooks so this is exactly the kind of suggestion I was hoping for. Secrecy is not a real concern for this (a public Dropbox URL is fine with us functionally, I just don't want to maintain data out of source control). Realistically, once the app is released any jailbreaker can dig through the assets anyway, so I'm not going to inconvenience myself for a false sense of security.

Comment: If your central repo is bare (no working tree), which is the usual case, you'll probably want to look into the `git archive` command.